# Retrieving HTML tags from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, json, mongodb, pug

I have this object into **MongoDB**: [image]

I'm trying to retrieve the body content like `<script>` tag but it is drawing like a *String*.

This is the *Jade* file:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  body
    each post in posts
      div= post.title
      div= post.body
```

Finally, if I **Edit as HTML** the code in *ChromeDevTools* this is what returns

```
<div>&lt;script src='https://gist.github.com/benatespina/9446679.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell jade not to escape your HTML code by using `!=`:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  body
    each post in posts
      div!= post.title
      div!= post.body
```

Source in [Jade documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#unescapedbufferedcode)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  body
    each post in posts
      div= post.title
      div= !{post.body}
```